# How to browse for existing device driver?

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers

I have 1 unit of fingerprint scanner which is  [not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guULm.png) but the others are [fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJXi.png). So how can I look for the driver/inf file of working reader to work with the device which is not recognize?

When I tried to manually browse for driver, I can't find the manufacturer on the list?

[Device that is recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yycNR.png)

[Device that is not recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeFFj.png)

**EDIT**

I have 2 Futronics Fingerprint Scanner (USB interfaced). They are both working fine, but one day, one if the scanners suddenly not recognize. I already tried :

1. uninstall the driver and restart the pc
2. Plugged the scanner to other computer
3. Plugged the scanner to other port

But nothing works.

Now I want to browse the driver of the working scanner and use it to the scanner that does not recognize, but I don't know where it is located.

Comment: You can find the VendorID and ProductID in the Device Manager. With that you can google and find out which device it really is and hopefully find drivers for it.

Comment: Fingerprint sensor is in your laptop? Have you searched drivers from the system manufacturer website?

Comment: Please explain what are the troubleshooting's you have done so far.

Comment: if it was working, and now isn't then it probably isn't a driver issue. probably the hardware broke, which is why windows won't recognise it.